# Is there in bash scripts a way of using variables to specify different bash arrays

Tags: arrays, linux, bash, function

For example in this simple script

```
    #!/bin/bash
    
    declare -a MYARRAY1
    declare -a MYARRAY2
    
    function updatearray {
    ARRAY=$1
    VALUE=$2
    
    $ARRAY+=$VALUE
    
    }

    updatearray MYARRAY1  "yyyy "
    updatearray MYARRAY2  "bbbb "
    
    echo "${MYARRAY1[@]}"
    echo "${MYARRAY2[@]}"
    
    exit 0
```

Just results in "line 10: MYARRAY1+=yyyy: command not found" rather than updating the array.  This is actually for a more complex bash script I'm working on that has more arrays I want to update, so I'm hoping to avoid 'case' statements which would mean a big function body

Comment: You need bash 4.3 or later; the feature you want is called _namerefs_

Comment: By the way, it's better form to use POSIX function declarations -- `updatearray() {` with no `function`. See http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/scripting/obsolete

Answer (score 1):

You can use namerefs, but [take care](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/006):

```
updatearray () {
    declare -n a=$1
    a+=$2
}
```